# What is whole grain?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request, cibus

How do you say "whole grain" in Latin?
The expressions in Romance languages are fairly similar, and based on them I would guess *granum integrum*.
For example, I might say *panem grani integri edere malo*.
I did not manage to find any relevant passages from any era concerning whole grain in Latin.

The typical "partial grain" products are made by separating parts from whole grain, so it is fathomable that the Romans could have had a word for it.
But any era is fine here, it does not have to be classical.
And it doesn't even have to be attested as such; a clear analogy to other similarly "whole" things is acceptable.

If anyone can suggest an attested or otherwise well justified translation, I would be happy to hear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [*Apicius*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apicius) (which includes some "vulgar" Latin) speaks of a *piperis granum* (peppercorn) that is *solidum* or *integrum*:

> at, ubi coctum fuerit, levabis cum iure suo et in patellam alternis de trulla refundes cum **piperis grana integra** et nucleis pineis, ita ut per singula coria substernas diploidem, in laganum similiter. (4.2)

(I could be missing something, but I'm really not sure why **grana integra** is not ablative here...)

> Leporem farsum: nucleos integros, amygdala, nuces sive glandes concisas, **piperis grana solida**, pulpam de ipso lepore. (8.8)

It seems a fairly straightforward extrapolation to apply this to a grains as well, so I think your suggestion is good: **panis grani integri**.